# Sandboxed page in Chrome extension through iframe throwing error when passing messages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm getting the following error when trying to use my popup page for a chromium extension as a pipe for communication between the background page and a page displayed within an iframe on the popup.  I needed a sandboxed environment to run Vue.js in but need to be able to get data from `chrome.storage` and work with other such objects so I receive packets of data and send commands to the background page whenever necessary.

> Uncaught SecurityError: Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at "chrome-extension://kncjlbkddbibekfmmljfpibdgjfdegeb" from accessing a frame at "chrome-extension://kncjlbkddbibekfmmljfpibdgjfdegeb". The frame requesting access is sandboxed and lacks the "allow-same-origin" flag.

This is the code for the pipe popup page:

```js
//please look at it as if block comments aren't commented out
//this is needed  due to SO not having chrome.* available.
//although line comments are real comments.

let displayFrame = document.getElementById('displayFrame');
let displayPort = displayFrame.contentWindow;
/*
let backgroundPort = chrome.extension.connect({
  name : "Extension Connection"
});
*/

// Forwarding from background to index.
/*
backgroundPort.onMessage.addListener((msg) => {
  displayPort.postMessage(msg, "*");
});
*/

// Forwarding from index to background.
window.addEventListener("message", function(msg) {
  /*
    backgroundPort.postMessage({
      data : msg.data
    });
  */
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8' />
  <script src="../scripts/popup.js" defer>
  </script>

  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      opacity: 1.0;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      resize: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="width : 300px; height: 500px;">
  <iframe id="displayFrame" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" src="./index.html" style="width: 300px; height: 500px" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

The contents of `background.js` and `index.html/js` aren't important as I see it, they both properly pass messages to their respective sides of the above code and I've confirmed this message passing in console to be working.  The issue arises when any change is made in `index.js` to a Vue.js variable.  I've tried from the actual Vue object (`vm` in the docs) and from internally (attaching the message listener to the window at the mounted hook).   I believe the wrapped setters for each variable that allows Vue to watch for state changes is causing the issue and I was curious whether anyone knew how to get rid of the error.

I'm having no issues with the extension overall; the message passing and even the Vue variable setting / function calls work perfectly.  It's just that every time I open the popup page that error appears in the background pages console.  Is it something I should worry about, and can it be fixed?

Comment: The posted code wouldn't work since the popup.js runs before DOM has #displayFrame element but I guess it's an artifact of copypasting here. Anyway without a real [MCVE](/help/mcve) I think only someone who had exactly the same setup can help you. If I have to guess, the "Sandbox access violation" error in the background page can only mean it's a part of msg.data or you're unexpectedly loading the iframe in the background page too. In either case you should be able to debug the code and see where it comes from. Enabling "pause on exceptions" in devtools may help too.

Comment: @wOxxOm I didn't know about that devtool, will definitely see where I can get.  I think an MCVE is tough to put together for an extension, and this kind of advice is more than helpful!

Comment: Hmm tried the tool, but the error only shows up in the chome://extensions page as an error, and not thrown in the console.  May just end up having to ignore it.

Comment: BTW, to debug the popup, open it, right-click it, click inspect. It's a separate window.

Comment: Yup I know how to access the console for both the background page and popup pages.  Both aren't throwing the error in their respective consoles though, it just shows up in the chrome://extensions page as an error.  I think my problem is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306315/chrome-app-accessing-sandboxed-iframe-from-parent-window except that Vue.js is doing something that's not allowed rather than console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this problem has been solved.   The error was only occurring when setting a vue variable's value to the `event.source` on the index.js end `window.addEventListener("message", (event) => { ... })`.  I guess something with how Vue tracks the variables doesn't mesh with the variable being a window object of the sender.  **However I realized the sender was the parent to the iframe all along** and so I solved my issue by:

- Not sending the introduction packet that saved the `event.source` for command sending.
- And instead sending commands through `window.parent.postMessage` where before I was using `this.vueVariable.postMessage`.

I hope this helps anyone who comes across such an issue in the future, the solution was right under my nose the whole time.  There are no longer any errors in the extension and communication works both ways with setting working as well.